# <HTML> Write an output list with multiple values

Tags: javascript, html, output

I'm trying to print in my html page (article section) the results of a function that identifies and enlists prime numbers from a specified range. But right now only the last prime number is being printed.

Example: From 1 to 25
Desired output: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<script>
    //Um número é classificado como primo se ele é maior do que um e é divisível apenas por um e por ele mesmo
    //Apenas números naturais (positivos e inteiros) podem ser classificados como primos
    
    function listaNumPrimo(){
    
    var inicial = Number(document.getElementById("inicial").value)
    var final = Number(document.getElementById("final").value)
    if (inicial<=1){inicial=2}
    
    for (x=inicial; x<=final; x++){
        if (verificaNumPrimo(x) === false){
        } else {
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML='  '+x+'  ';
        }
    }
        function verificaNumPrimo(n){
            if (n<=2 && n<=1){
            return true;
            } else {
            for(var i=2; i<n; i++){
                if (n % i === 0) { 
                return false;                
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

<body>
    
<header>
    <h2><b>TESTE PRÁTICO</b></h2>
    <p>Minicamp Data & Dev</p>
</header>

<section>
    <nav>
    <p>Nessa página vamos construir uma função para definir quais os números primos em um intervalo<br>
        Primeiramente, digite um número inicial e final do intervalo nos campos abaixo</p>
        
        <form>
            <label for="inicial">Número inicial:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="inicial" name="inicial" min="2"><br><br>
            <label for="final">Número Final:</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="final" name="final" min="2"><br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="listaNumPrimo()" value="Enviar">
        </form>
    </nav>

    <article>
    <p>A lista de números primos é:</p>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
    </article>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are not storing the value of First result and the variable x is getting replaced with the latest value so that's the reason you are not the list that contains the value like 1, 25, etc. Please use below code:

```
for (x=inicial; x<=final; x++){
        if (verificaNumPrimo(x) === false){
        } else {
        y=document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=  x+','+y ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add + before = in result show line

```
        for (x=inicial; x<=final; x++){
            if (verificaNumPrimo(x) === false){
            } else {
            document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML+='  '+x+'  ';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows

```
function listaNumPrimo(){
    const inicial = Number(document.getElementById("inicial").value)
    const final = Number(document.getElementById("final").value)
    const resultado = document.getElementById('resultado')

    const isPrimeNumber = number => Array.apply(null, number > 0 ? new Array(number): []).map((_, numberIdx) => number % (numberIdx + 1) === 0 ? (numberIdx + 1) : null).filter(item => !!item).length === 2
    const verifyPrimeNumbers = (initial, limit) => Array.apply(null, limit > 0 ? new Array(limit - initial + 1): []).map((_, limitIdx) => isPrimeNumber(initial + limitIdx) ? (initial + limitIdx) : null).filter(item => !!item)
    
    const results = verifyPrimeNumbers(inicial, final)

    resultado.innerHTML = '';
    results.map((number, numberIdx) => {
        resultado.innerHTML += number;
        const complement = numberIdx < (results.length - 1) ? (numberIdx === (results.length - 2) ? ' e ' : ', ') : '.';
        resultado.innerHTML += complement;
    })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuAsG.png)